# Cannot detect the vehicle when using YOLO pre-trained model

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I tried to detect the vehicle from image with using YOLO-v1 pre-trained model.

[This](https://github.com/subodh-malgonde/vehicle-detection) is the source code that I have worked with.

When I ran this, there was no error, but I couldn't any detected car with box drawn on the image.

On the debugging with python, I saw the yolo_output_to_car_boxes() function returned empty list of boxes.

I couldn't solve this problem even I have tried.

If anyone help me to solve this, I will very happy.

Thanks.
Du.

Comment: This is too broad, it could be that YOLO just missed a vehicle (a false negative), and this is perfectly OK because it doesn't reach 100% detection rate (just look at the mAP).

Comment: Hi Matias. Thank you for yor response. I want only detection testing with pretrained model and weights , not want to training. Then the yolo-tiny.weights and testing image will be not enough for it. And in my case it didn't detect any car then it means the detection accurate is 0%?

Comment: did you try the images given in your link? Probably, your yolo model should detect at least the objects that are marked in the test image outputs. If not, probably there's something wrong with your code or your setup.